# How to set HTTP header in MS Power Automate (Flow) custom connector using policy template

Tags: json, power-automate

I am trying to create a custom connector in MS Flow ( now rebranded to MS Power Automate).  I am trying to add a custom header in my action request using values from the connection, I read the documentation that this is possible using policy template:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/policy-templates/setheader/setheader#input-parameters

In the example provided by microsoft here, it's also possible: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatformConnectors/blob/master/samples/Facebook/apiProperties.json

Here is how I set it up in my apiProperties.json.  When the user first make a connection, I ask for their IP, username, and password.  Using the simple authentication type.:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "capabilities": [],
    "connectionParameters": {
      "ip": {
        "type": "string",
        "uiDefinition": {
          "constraints": {
            "clearText": true,
            "required": "true",
            "tabIndex": 0
          },
          "description": "Your IP",
          "displayName": "IP",
          "tooltip": "Provide your IP"
        }
      },
      "username": {
        "type": "string",
        "uiDefinition": {
          "constraints": {
            "clearText": true,
            "required": "true",
            "tabIndex": 1
          },
          "description": "Your username",
          "displayName": "Username",
          "tooltip": "Provide your username"
        }
      },
      "password": {
        "type": "securestring",
        "uiDefinition": {
          "constraints": {
            "clearText": false,
            "required": "true",
            "tabIndex": 2
          },
          "description": "Your password",
          "displayName": "Password",
          "tooltip": "Provide your password"
        }
      }
    },
    "iconBrandColor": "#ff5c10",
    "policyTemplateInstances": [
      {
        "parameters": {
          "x-ms-apimTemplate-operationName": [
            "MyAction"
          ],
          "x-ms-apimTemplate-policySection": "Request",
          "x-ms-apimTemplateParameter.existsAction": "override",
          "x-ms-apimTemplateParameter.name": "IP",
          "x-ms-apimTemplateParameter.value": "@connectionParameters('ip')"
        },
        "templateId": "setheader",
        "title": "IP"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the policyTemplateInstances section, you can see that I pass the IP variable as a header parameter.

In the apiDefinitions file, I set the security to be basic:

```
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "undefined": {
      "type": "basic"
    }
  },
```

So the error I run into is that it actually doesn't pass the control room ip in the action header, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ah it turns out my solution does indeed work, will leave it here for future viewers